# html check for Chrome only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Is there a way to check for only chrome and not both chrome and safari? Like they way you can do it for firefox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
 //some css
 }
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking. If you mean `-webkit-`, that applies to Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Yeah I know I'm looking for something like that but chrome specific

Comment: CSS `-webkit-` is part of WebKit, unspecific to Chrome or Safari. In short, you can't target Chrome-only in CSS.